# How to scrape tag information from questions on Stack Exchange

Tags: python, tags, extract

My problem is that I want to create a data base of all of the questions, answers, and most importantly, the tags, from a certain (somewhat small) Stack Exchange. The relationships among tags (e.g. tags more often used together have a strong relation) could reveal a lot about the structure of the community and popularity or interest in certain sub fields.

So, what is the easiest way to go through a list of questions (that are positively ranked) and extract the tag information using Python?

Comment: Why scrape when you can get the data directly? http://api.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get the shared-tag count for all questions is to use the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/).

```
import requests

r = requests.get(
    'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/python/related?pagesize=3&site=stackoverflow')

for item in r.json()['items']:
   print("{name} shares {count} tags with Python".format(**item))
```

If this doesn't satisfy your need, there are many other API queries available.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the site to find the URL that shows the information you want, then look at the page source to see how it has been formatted.

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to scrape the pages use the [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html) library.
2. Parse the text using the [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) library.
3. Place the data into a database.

The difficult thing is going to be structuring your database and developing queries that reveal what you want.

---